# How can i understand Python about list. help me please

Tags: python, list, function

```
score = [88,95,70,100,99,80,78,50]
score[1:4]=[]
print(score)
```

I expected this code snippet to print `[95,70,100]`. Instead, it printed out `[88, 99, 80, 78, 50]`. Why is this so?

Comment: According to you code at line two you remove indices 1,2,3 from list score. So it remove 95 70 and 100 from list. For printing 95 70 100 the code should be score=score[1:4]

Answer (score 0):

On the second line, the code takes a list slice and then sets it to the empty list, effectively removing them from the original `score` list.

The following line prints the `score` list, with items originally at indices `1`, `2`, and `3` removed. You're mixing up the items remaining in the score list with the ones that were just removed.